# ajaxForm + fancbox makes trouble Internet Explorer 8

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, fancybox, ajaxform

The IE 8 make some trouble with sending a REQUEST to an AJAX-File. Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#reportform").ajaxForm({
    success: function(responseText){
        $.fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :       'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :       'elastic',
            'speedIn'               :       600,
            'speedOut'              :       200,
            'overlayShow'   :       false,
            'width':        600,
            'height':       400,
            'content' : responseText
        });
    }
}); 
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="reportform" action="/ajax.php">
[ .... ]
<input type="submit" value="{{lang_generate_report}}">
</form>
```

In ajax.php I do a print_r($_REQUEST) an I get in the Mozilla Firefox and Internet Exlporer 11 the correct results. In Internet Explorer 8 I get an empty Array with no values inside.

What could be wrong?

Comment: have you tried `$.fancybox(responseText, { // options })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem by myself. It was the latest update from http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

I took a version earlier (3.46.0) from the branch which works with IE 8 and all other browsers for me.